# GCP : There are no enabled services with quotas.for new Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

I have create a new project through console in GCP.

But when I tried to allocate services in `Quotas (IAM & Admin -> Quotas)` it shows

```
"There are no enabled services with quotas."
```

can anyone guide how to allocate/enable services for new project.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might means that "there are no services enabled with a quota set", meaning that most probably the project contain disabled services with quotas in them.

Try going to `APIs & Services` and click on `+ ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES`. Then if you enable the desired API the quotas for that API should be visible in the `Quotas (IAM & Admin -> Quotas)` page you mentioned earlier.